# Jenkins build email notification by parsing log

Tags: jenkins, build-server, alerting

I am using Jenkins to deploy in multiple servers. There are 4 backend servers are running. I have a script called `deploy.sh` in each server. At the time of deployment, Jenkins create a ssh session and run the `deploy.sh` script in each server one by one. But, sometimes it shows error in build console log `"Errno : can not allocate memory"` for few servers and then move to the next servers. I am looking for a solution, which will send me an email whenever there is a "error" keyword in the Jenkins log.

I found this link :- https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Log+Parser+Plugin

But, it doesn't provide email notification and I am looking for a better solution.

Comment: check the server memory where jenkins is running or java memory parameters

Comment: I am not looking to solve this particular error. But, want to setup an alert system, so that I get notification in future

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Log+Parser+Plugin, you can use the Mailer plugin to send a mail notification when build is failed or unstable ( https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Mailer ).

- Install it from the plugins management
- Setup the admin mail ( Configure System > Jenkins Location )
- Fill in the smtp server configuration. ( Configure System > E-mail Notification )

**Note:** *You can use any smtp server including google smtp if do not have.
Many tutorials are availble for using google smtp as a relay.
You can test before saving the configuration*

- Use *Log Parser Plugin* to mark the job as failed or unstable when error occurs
- Finally configure your job to send you a notification when the build is marked as failed ( Post-build Actions > E-mail Notifications > *Fill in the recipient field and check "Send e-mail for every unstable build"* )

Hope this will helps!